# Visual Basic for Applications Splash Screen

Tags: vba, splash-screen, userform

I make one splash scrren with a text and image..but I am not able to remove user form border. I only need my image in splash screen which exactly fits in excel boundaries:

[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be the same size as Excel (which may or may not be maximised), or do you want it to occupy the full size of the screen?

Comment: A splash screen shouldn't be *that* obnoxious. Anyway there's no *exposed* way to hide the title bar of a `UserForm`, so you need to invoke Win32 API functions. See http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/create-awesome-excel-splash-screen-for-your-spreadsheet/

Comment: Curious, what do you need a splash screen for? Are you doing any actual processing, or just displaying a "hi" screen for the heck of it? Take Excel's own splash screen as an example.

Comment: # YowE3K same size as excel.(row and column portion 1-17)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms, go into the Designer of the form, go to the properties, and change `FormBorderStyle` to `none` - that way the use border will be hidden.